# How to import and arrange a data set separated by comma?

Tags: r

This is a very specific question. I have data that looks like below but way much bigger than that and many many files (not only one file).

```
TOURERG_ID,RawDataID,IndexNo,IndexValue
19003771,11,240,1.1858652499
19003771,11,241,1.177533477
19003771,11,242,1.1704270598
19003771,11,243,1.1620838731
19003771,11,244,1.1540253051
19003771,11,245,1.1464526996
19003771,11,246,1.1394576168
19003771,11,247,1.1328267903
19003771,11,248,1.1258228114
19003771,11,249,1.1171001937

19003771,11,249,1.1237839518
19003771,11,250,1.1113389261
19003771,11,251,1.0938118176
19003771,11,252,1.0704340703
19003771,11,253,1.0418955374
19003771,11,254,1.0104241602
19003771,11,255,0.97917606379
19003771,11,256,0.95110409662
19003771,11,257,0.9277733067
19003771,11,258,0.90865127357

19000693,11,240,1.1952986902
19000693,11,241,1.1867360653
19000693,11,242,1.1793816406
19000693,11,243,1.1707059267
19000693,11,244,1.1623008189
19000693,11,245,1.1543825533
19000693,11,246,1.1470470507
19000693,11,247,1.1400880358
19000693,11,248,1.1327804778
19000693,11,249,1.1237839518

19000693,11,252,1.0704340703
19000693,11,253,1.0418955374
19000693,11,254,1.0104241602
19000693,11,255,0.97917606379
19000693,11,256,0.95110409662
19000693,11,257,0.9277733067
19000693,11,258,0.90865127357
19000693,11,259,0.89118257832
19000693,11,260,0.87161311454
19000693,11,261,0.84625725399
```

What I want to have is as below. 
This means from each box, only keep the first value before the comma, add ID to it and _1 it the first one and _2 to the second and
then keep all values after the last comma.

```
    ID_19003771_1   ID_19003771_2  ID_19000693_1   ID_19000693_2
1.1858652499   1.1237839518    1.1952986902   1.0704340703
1.177533477    1.1113389261    1.1867360653   1.0418955374
1.1704270598   1.0938118176    1.1793816406   1.0104241602
1.1620838731   1.0704340703    1.1707059267   0.97917606379
1.1540253051   1.0418955374    1.1623008189   0.95110409662
1.1464526996   1.0104241602    1.1543825533   0.9277733067
1.1394576168   0.97917606379   1.1470470507   0.90865127357
1.1328267903   0.95110409662   1.1400880358   0.89118257832
1.1258228114   0.9277733067    1.1327804778   0.87161311454
1.1171001937   0.90865127357   1.1237839518   0.84625725399
```

To be honest, I would not even know where to start

Comment: What is the desired output, 4 data.frames, a list of length 4 or something else?

Comment: I would just use `fread` to read all the data in, then `split` if you really need to and drop the irrelevant columns.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik  I gave an example of desired output,  I would like to have it as data frame and not list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.table` with `blank.lines.skip=FALSE` to read the blank lines as `NA`.  Use the `NA` rows to create a grouping variable ('gr') and `split` the last column with the 'gr'.  We can name the list elements with the
'TOURERG_ID'.  If there are same 'TOUREG_ID's, use `make.unique` to create a unique 'ID'.  Based on the comments, if we need separate data.frames in the global environment, use `list2env` (though not recommended) as most of the operations can be done within the list itself.

```
df1 <- read.table('Nemo3.txt', sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
         header=TRUE,blank.lines.skip=FALSE)
indx <- is.na(df1[,1])
gr <- cumsum(indx)
lst <- split(df1[4][-which(indx),,drop=FALSE], gr[-which(indx)])
nm1 <- tapply(df1[,1], gr, 
            FUN= function(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
names(lst) <- paste('ID', make.unique(as.character(nm1)), sep="_")
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

If we need to get a single dataset with a grouping column,

```
library(tidyr)
res <- unnest(lst, group)
```

Comment: hello .  first error is in list2env (lst, envir =Globalenv) object 'Globalenv' not found

Comment: @Nemo you're missing a dot.

Comment: @akrun that is already a dream program for me , Thanks Akrun like always! but now it creates over 1000 seperated file, maybe I was not accurate enough in my question. If I could put them all in one file, like each column one of this files, it would be amazing !!!!

Comment: @Roman Luštrik thanks Roman, you were right, I am even not good at copy and pasting !

Comment: @Nemo That would be easier.  After we name the `lst` i.e. `names(lst) <- paste('ID', ....); library(tidyr); res <- unnest(lst, group)` gives the output in a single dataframe with a 'group' column